# how to load ajax response in current child element?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am triying to add ajax loaded content in child element of current div item, but it not works , unable to find out where is the problem.

here is HTML code:

```
<div class="thumb-pitch">
<span class="pitch-count" ></span>
</div>  
<div class="thumb-pitch"> 
<span class="ditch-count"></span>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$('.thumb-pitch').click(function() {
var id= $(this).attr('cid');
var dataString = 'idea_id='+ id;   
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',     
  url:"<?php echo base_url();?>users/user_votes/user_pitch",
  data:dataString,
  success: function(response) {  
   //alert(response);          
  $(this).find('span').html(response);
  }
});
});
```

Comment: did the ajax response is ok??

Comment: Is there a `/` before users in the url and $(this) wont be what you think

Comment: please share the **response** object details ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the reference of `$(this)` in a variable and then use that variable in the sucess callback handler.

Use

```
$('.thumb-pitch').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('cid');
    var $this = $(this); //Store this reference in a variable
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>users/user_votes/user_pitch",
        data: {"idea_id" : id},
        success: function(response) {
            //alert(response);          
            $this.find('span').html(response); //Use the reference variable here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use children() for this

$(this).children('span').html(response);